# Associating 3 Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm a little confused on which type of association I should set up in my application.

I have these three models: Booking, Availability and Facility

A facility puts up 1 hour blocks of available time. So I'd say `Availability: belongs_to :facility`.

I'm trying to represent that a booking could have many availabilities. In that if I book from 1-3PM that's two 1 hour blocks and I'd like for that to be represented in 1 record in the Bookings table.

I was thinking I should set up `Bookings: has_many :availability`
but then I was reading about `has_many though` and I wasn't sure if it would be more appropriate to do Facilities has many Bookings through Availability...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would absolutely do a `has_many :through` association here, but I'd make the association between `Availability` and `Booking` slightly different than a typical `has_many :through` association:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :availabilities
  has_many :bookings, through: :availabilities
end

class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facility
  has_one :booking
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :availability
end
```

The reason I prefer this association style is because in a typical `has_many :through`, you have two entities sharing relationships with one another through a third entity (e.g. Patients and Doctors sharing a relationship `through` an entity called `Appointment`, as explained by the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)). This example is different, however, in that `Booking` shouldn't hold any positive relationship to `Facility`--the relationship should merely be a by-product of an open `Availability`.

Comment: What if things get more complicated and say I have User model as well. My Bookings model already has a `belongs_to :user`, would adding `belongs_to :availability` to it be okay?

Comment: This is  a more accurate example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02dL9XqcJg5akU4aGdwMjgxWTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, I noticed  you have `has_one  :booking` in the availability model. However, wouldn't that prevent the booking of multiple availabilities? So if I  reserve 3 availabilities, could they be associated with 1 booking?

Comment: That wouldn't make much sense from an object-oriented perspective, though, would it? If you have an availability (eg, a home showing from 11-12), you're going to fulfill that with a single booking from Fred. You wouldn't want Fred, Lisa, and Tom to all show up for the same availability—that would refute the design philosophy.

Comment: Yea i see what you mean. I think I'm getting confused between how it's done here with Objects compared to how I'd do the relationships in something like Access or Entity Relationship tools.